# why i geet this error whene i want to update my app

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I need your help about an error, I have an application in the Play store and I want to update it but I get this error, can anyone help me plz?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever change the SDK build version?
Try update your project and Android Studio, later you remake APK realease to updade in play store. So, remember change the version of apk too.

Comment: It's not really the problem when I put the app as a new project in play store I didn't get this error, but when I wanna update an existing app with the new app I get the error